# Creating Django object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a Django model Sounds in models.py:

```
class Sounds(models.Model):
    consonant = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    vowel = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

In views.py, I can create objects with:

```
Sounds.objects.create(consonant="b", vowel="a")
```

Obviously, I can't just do the same in a javascript file. Does anyone have any tips of what I could do instead?

Thank you!

Comment: an approach is: send a request to a specific view via ajax.

Comment: That's really the *only* approach, in fact.